# How to select the Average per WORK Day/Week/Month/60 Days/90 Days when not all days are in table?

Tags: sql, datetime, sqlite

OK, So after a lot of research I am still stuck. I get the simple basics:

I can select average of all values using a group by statement. grouping where the dates are within my range and by the average I want.

```
Select AVG(Qty)
From (
            Select Sum(ItemQty) As Qty
            From ReceivedInfo
            Where DateUsed >= '2014-04-01' 
                         AND DateUsed < '2014-04-30'
            Group By Date(DateUsed)
)
```

the Issue here is that I need to include days that aren't in the table too. All Workdays should be accounted for even days that don't have an entry. I am not sure how to get an average of Qty per day (or month, or 60 days and so on) including all, and only, workdays from a data range. Exclude Weekends.

Would it be enough to do something like:

```
Select Sum(QTy) / (julianday('2014-04-30') - julianday('2014-04-01' )) - (((julianday('2014-04-30') - julianday('2014-04-01' )) / 7 ) * 2) As Average
From (
            Select Sum(ItemQty) As Qty
            From ReceivedInfo
            Where DateUsed >= '2014-04-01' 
                         AND DateUsed < '2014-04-30'          
)
```

Or Do  I have to determine the number of work days outside of the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final query should work fine if you want the missing values to be treated as `0`.  You can, however, simplify it.  So, to a close approximation:

```
Select Sum(QTy) / (5.0/7 * (julianday('2014-04-30') - julianday('2014-04-01' ) ) )
From ReceivedInfo
Where DateUsed >= '2014-04-01' AND DateUsed < '2014-04-30';
```

Of course, this is just an approximation of the number of work days (which is similar to your proposed solution).  A full solution would use cumbersome day-of-week arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

A while back I saw someone do something rather interesting with a CTE that solved a similar problem: perhaps this would work for you?

```
WITH DateRange(Date) AS
     (
         SELECT '2014-04-01' Date

         UNION ALL

         SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, Date) Date
         FROM DateRange
         WHERE Date < '2014-04-30'
     )

     SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Date, 121) -- either SELECT from or JOIN to this table
     FROM DateRange
     WHERE DatePart(dw, Date) NOT IN (1,7) -- this could limit it to Mon-Fri only
```

EDIT: I *think* that the following would be the linkage for you to include this in your resultset:

```
Select AVG(Qty)
From (
            Select Sum(ItemQty) As Qty
            From 
                DateRange 
                 LEFT JOIN 
                ReceivedInfo ON 
                    DateRange.Date = ReceivedInfo.DateUsed
            Where DateRange.Date >= '2014-04-01' 
                             AND DateRange.Date < '2014-04-30'
            Group By DateRange.Date
)
```

EDIT 2: removed variables as per commenter below.  Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: SQLite does not have variables.

Comment: Sorry, missed that tag in the original question: I'll modify appropriately.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. At least not in SQLite